# Prove or disprove: if $c, n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $n \in \mathbb N$ we have: $f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$ then $2^{f(n)}\le 8^{c\cdot g(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, asymptotics

> Prove or disprove: if there're constants $c, n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $n \in \mathbb N$ we have:  $f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$ then $2^{f(n)}\le 8^{c\cdot g(n)}$.
>
> $f,g$ are increasing functions.

Can I prove that it's wrong using limits?

For example, let $f(n)=n$, $g(n)=2n$ so:
$$
n\le 2n\qquad c=2
$$
then:
$$
2^{n}\le 8^{2n}=2^{6n}
$$
But:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{2^{6n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2^{5n}}=0
$$
Which means that $2^n<8^{2n}$ and not $2^n\le 8^{2n}$

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ positive? Also, if you're supposed to show $\leq$, and you actually show $<$, then that's considered a proof, not disproof. Using $\leq$ doesn't mean that they _have_ to equal at some point. Just that you're allowing it to happen. Finally, your title and question body disagree on whether $c$ appears in the exponent of $8$.

Comment: There is information missing here. Are you to show things for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? For the limit? ...

Comment: @Arthur I edited the question. So if the claim is true how do I prove it? I guess I proved the case if $f<g$ so the proof for $f=g$ is trivial?

Comment: No, you checked it in one specific case, and that is never proof on its own (although it is some times possible to prove that you only need to check one specific case, and then check that case). And you haven't adressed my first concern: Are $f$ and $g$ always positive? Because if $f(n) = g(n) = -2$, then they are (technically) increasing, $c = 1$ works, but $2^{f(n)}>8^{g(n)}$.

Comment: @Arthur it would also not hold if $f=5n$ and $g=n$ then asymptotically $2^{5n}>2^n$ right?

Comment: But then you need to use a value of $c$ which is at least $5$ to make $f(n)\leq c\cdot g(n)$, which means we're not comparing $2^{5n}$ to $8^n$, but $2^{5n}$ to $8^{5\cdot n}$.

Comment: @Arthur I know it's my mistake but I think $c$ shouldn't be there as I meant $c$ exists such that $f(n) \le cg(n)$ to show that $f\le g$. Originally it was if $f=O(g)$ then $2^{f(n)}=O(8^{g(n)})$ in big-O notation if you're familiar. So I think my "translation" is incorrect.

Comment: That should mean $f(n)\leq c\cdot 8^{g(n)}$.

Comment: @Arthur so in that case a counter example could also be $f=5n, g=n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you have proven $2^n < 8^{2n}$, then you have proven $2^n \leq 8^{2n}$. Hence you have not proven that it is wrong.

Let $f(n)= -1 - \frac{1}{n}=g(n) < 0$

Since $g(n) < 0$, $3g(n) < g(n)=f(n)$.

Note that $2^x$ is an increasing function,

We have $2^{3g(n)} < 2^{f(n)}$, that is $8^{cg(n)} < 2^{f(n)}$.

Remark:

Suppose you have further information that $f$ and $g$ are positive. (credit: Authur).

Try to use the fact that $2^x$ is an increasing function to prove the statement.

Also, note that we have not use the properties that $f$ and $g$ are increasing function in the proof.

Comment: if the functions were also positive then the claim would be correct?

Comment: yes, we can use the property that $2^x$ is an increasing function to prove it. give it a try. =)

Comment: It seems trivial to me: if $f(n)\le cg(n)$ are positive and increasing then $2^{f(n)}\le 2^{3cg(n)}$ are also increasing

Comment: Note that $f(n) \leq 3cg(n)$ depends on the fact that $cg(n)$ is positive.

Comment: I actually just realized that I completely overlooked the fact that $f:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$. So they are positive. It's too late to change the question but just for me to know, given all these conditions if $f\le cg$ then $2^{f(n)}\le 2^{3cgn}$ right?

Comment: yes, that would just be a special case.

Comment: what if $f=5n,g=n$ then asymptotically $5n\le n$ but $2^{5n}>2^{3n}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62158/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-yos).